# Sed to print only first pattern match of the line

Tags: sed

I have some data like

```
<td><a href="data1">abc</a> ... <a href="data2">abc</a> ... <a href="data3">abc</a>
```

**( Would refer to above line as `data` in code below )**

I need `data1` in between the first `"` and `"` so I do

```
echo 'data' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/'
```

but it returns me the **last string** in between `"` and `"` always, i.e in this case it would return me `data3` instead instead of `data1`

In order to get `data1`, I end up doing

```
echo 'data' | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*".*".*".*".*/\1/'
```

How do I get `data1` without this much of redundancy in `sed`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `.*` in the regex pattern is greedy, it matches as long a string as it can, so the quotes that are matched will be the last ones.

Since the separator is only one character here, we can use an inverted bracket group to match anything but a quote, i.e. `[^"]`, and then repeats of that to match a number of characters that aren't quotes.

```
$ echo '... "foo" ... "bar" ...' | sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
foo
```

Another way would be to just remove everything up to the first quote, then remove everything starting from the (new) first quote:

```
$ echo '... "foo" ... "bar" ...' | sed 's/^[^"]*"//; s/".*$//'
foo
```

---

In Perl regexes, the `*` and `+` specifiers can be made non-greedy by appending a question mark, so `.*?` would anything, but as few characters/bytes as possible.

Comment: `cut -d \" -f 2` should be enough

Comment: Your solutions worked, but I really didn't understand the working of `[^"]*`. Could you please give an explanation or provide a link for it's explanation

Comment: To complicate things further, see also `*+` in `perl` for super-greedy (won't  give anything back, won't backtrack). `s/^.*+"(.*?)".*/$1/` would not even match as the `.*+` would match the whole line and not backtrack to allow the rest to be matched. `s/^[^"]*+"(.*?)".*/` could in theory improve performance though I'd expect `perl` would know how to optimise it in that case.

Answer (score 4):

I won't bore you with the classic warning against using simple regular expressions to parse HTML. Suffice it to say that you should use a dedicated parser instead. That said, the issue here is that `sed` uses greedy matching. So it will always match the longest possible string. This means that your `.*` goes on for ever and matches the entire line.

You could do this in `sed` (see below), but using a tool that allows non-greedy matches would be simpler:

```
$ perl -pe 's/.*?"(.*?)".*/$1/' file
data1
```

---

Since `sed` doesn't support non-greedy matches, you need some other trickery. The simplest would be to use the "not quotes" approach in [ikkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/383154/22222). Here's an alternative:

```
$ rev file | sed 's/.*"\(.*\)".*/\1/' | rev
data1
```

This just reverses the file (`rev`), uses your original approach which now works since the 1st occurrence is now the last, and then reverses the file back again.

Comment: `rev` is nice until I learn `perl` regex, thanks

Comment: `HTML::Parser` or `HTML::TokeParser` are good modules to start with for parsing HTML.  and add in `LWP` if you need to fetch the HTML first (e.g. write a web-scraping robot).

Answer (score 4):

Here are a couple of ways you could pull out data1 from your input:

```
grep -oP '^[^"]*"\K[^"]*'

sed -ne '
   /\n/!{y/"/\n/;D;}
   P
'

perl -lne '/"([^"]*)"/ and print($1),last'
```

Answer (score 3):

While Question is not tagged with `awk`, but why not using it as it's simply as it is:

```
awk -F\" '{print $2}' infile.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use a non greedy search using perl regular expression's look ahead and look behind:

```
cat data | grep -Po '(?<=href=").*?(?=")' | head -n1
```

Comment: `grep -Po '^.*?href="\K.*?(?=")'` to return only the first of each line.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to position `sed` to the first of multiple matches in a line, simply first modify the first match:

```
echo abcmatchdefmatchghimatchjkl | \
sed -e "s/match/m#1#atch/" \
 -e "s/^.*m#1#atch/match/" 
gives the result
matchdefmatchghimatchjkl
```

This can be modified for e.g. the second match:

```
echo abcmatchdefmatchghimatchjkl | sed \
 -e "s/match/m#1#atch/" \
 -e "s/match/m#2#atch/" \
 -e "s/^.*m#2#atch/match/"
```

gives the result

```
matchghimatchjkl
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please note, though, that the OP is explicitly looking for a solution to extract string between double-quotes (`" ... "`). You may want to edit your answer to explain how this can be achieved using your approach.