# Verbally reading sed regular expression caret inside brackets, asterisk outside brackets

Tags: sed

This is a followup of my previous question "[Sed to print only first pattern match of the line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383150/sed-to-print-only-first-pattern-match-of-the-line)"

The data I'm working on

```
... "one" ... "two" ... "three" ...
```

I wanted `one` to be printed and the answer I accepted was this

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

I searched and tried to understand this regular expression but I couldn't wrap my head around this one.

What I understand is:

- `[^"]` means do not match `"`
- `*` means match 0 any number of characters preceded by `*`
- `\(` and `\)` means store anything matching in between them to be referenced later by the corresponding number i.e in our case it is only `\1`
- `.*` is greedy and means any number of characters

I don't understand what `[^"]*` here means.

**How do I verbally read this whole regular expression so that I understand what's going on here**

```
sed 's/[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \(                        group and capture to \1:
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [^"]*                    any character except: '"' (0 or more
                             times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \)                        end of \1
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  "                        '"'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
```

The second component of the `sed` command invokes `\1` to use what was 'captured' in the parenthetical.  It should be noted that the entire `sed` command is not itself a regular expression.  In the construct `s/needle/pin/g`, the regular expression is `needle` or, if you like your regular expressions "wrapped" (e. g. for use in `awk`), `/needle/`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti Actually, the `.` also matches the newline, but a long as you go line by line, there is no newline to be matched.

Comment: `sed` parses its input file line by line, so.

Answer (score 1):

Since `[^"]*` means "any number of characters that is not a quote", and since `sed` regex are greedy, `[^"]*` ensures that the quote that follows is the first quote in the string. The second similar regex ensures that the quote that follows is the second one in the string. `.*` matches what follows that second quote.

Therefore `[^"]*"\([^"]*\)".*` means "match the whole line and put the second quote-delimited field in `\1`".